# Why should I use get_template_directory() when include files?

Tags: functions, directory, include

When I include files in wordpress I noticed that *include* works fine without get_template_directory(). *Include* even works fine without parenteses.

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/includes/front/enqueue.php' );
```

works fine as well as

```
include '/includes/front/enqueue.php';
```

Could anyone please explain, should I use get_template_directory() when inlcude files in wordpress?
And is it "ok" to not use parentheses after include?

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_directory()` can be filtered. This can be useful when a plugin wants to interact with your theme, for example when you want to write custom plugins to extend the theme without changing it.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'template_directory', function( $template_dir, $template, $theme_root ) {
    if ( some_condition( $theme_root ) ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template';
    }
});
```

`include` is an expression, not a function, so omitting parentheses is fine.

Also note that `plugin_dir_path()` has a trailing slash while `get_template_directory()` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I see.

Comment: there's also the possibility that another file with the same name or subpath might exist in a higher priority place that gets loaded instead, though that is rarer. Overall this answer is the primary reason. @redgard if this answers your question could you consider clicking the button to mark it as the accepted answer?